# Iterate a script over files using os.walk in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, os.walk

I am trying to iterate a script in jupyter using os.walk but
i get an error: unrecognized arguments: name
my code is

```
import os

filename = "C:\\Georef\\CH4\\7"         
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filename):        
   for name in files:        
         %run "C:\Scripts\CEP\h5raster\h5raster.py" -x s5p:CH4 -i str(os.path.join(root, name)) -o "{}"
```

Comment: Could you use code formatting for your question content? In Python, indentation is not optional, so it's not immediately clear if your problem is related to that.

Comment: Yes Thank you I did the edition